# How to get array in array using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

in my jquery, i want to get value array in array from query mysql. but when im check in console, i get object in array. i will write example code with sample data and data from my query mysql.

```
var locationsSample = [
              [-6.175656, 106.812630,'ONSHORE',1,'id1'],
              [-6.192848, 106.822027,'OFFSHORE',1,'id2'],
              [-6.164234, 106.328973,'FABRICATION SHOP',1,'id3'],
              [-0.594009, 100.735315,'SUMATERA',0,'id4'],
              [5.168138, 97.124416,'SUMATERA ACEH',1,'id5'] 
        ]; 
console.log(locationsSample); 
from console => Array [ Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5] ]  this is a true.
```

and this is my php code:

filename : jsonarray.php

```
$qry="SELECT latitude,longitude,project_name,status,id_tbl_project_map FROM tbl_project_map";
$res = mysql_query($qry) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$rows= array();
while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $rows[]=$data;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

and jquery to call file jsonarray.php :

```
locations = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            url:"jsonarray.php?id=2",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(retqry){
                locations = retqry;
                console.log(locations); 
from console => Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ] this is a false. why i'm get a Object not Array[5] from example code in top
            } 
        });
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Do the `Object` items have the correct data? Your using `mysql_fetch_assoc` and your JSON encoding them, so it's going to interpret it as an Object. (*Note you may want to use `mysqli` instead as `mysql` is deprecated and has security flaws*)

Comment: when i click the Object in console, and then show a valid data or data true.

Comment: Alright since they are correct then there isn't anything wrong here. I explained why it's an `Object` in my last comment, which is due to an associative array item in PHP will be interpreted as an object in JSON.

Comment: then how do i get the value of the array? for example i want to get 'latitude' value.

Comment: Did you try `locations[i].latitude`? `i` being the index of the array element you are looking at.

Comment: hey @SpencerWieczorek thank you, it work. i'm forget to get value array must be structure that's array. im alway try like this 'locations.latitude' and this is false :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to archive your requirement,

```
locations = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url:"jsonarray.php?id=2",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(retqry){
        // locations = retqry;
        // console.log(locations);
        var Data = [];
        $.each(retqry, function(your_key, your_val){
            Data.push({
                your_key:your_val,
            });
        });

        locations = Data;
    } 
});
```

Please note this code is not tested might you need to change code as per your need. Hope this works for you!

Greetings!